# How to convert pls_number to varchar2 in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I tried to convert `pls_integer` to `varchar2` using `to_char` but it is not working.
I also tried `pls_integer` to `number` and `number` to `varchar2` using `to_number` and `to_char` methods, but that also not working. I am getting an error :

```
Pls00306 - wrong number or types of arguments in call 'to_number'.
```

Can you please help.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d67cca15b7d533117113fb17bd9009f8

Comment: I need to assign value of pls_interger to another variable of data type varchar2. I don't want to print it :(

Comment: can you show us what exactly you did ..?

Comment: [**EDIT**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51374232/edit) your question and add the code that generates the error. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to do anything special just assign. Oracle allows implicit data type conversion between pls_integer and varchar2. [See table 3-10 at the bottom of this page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/datatypes.htm#BABJHGJD)

```
declare
  l_number pls_integer;
  l_varchar varchar2(1);
begin
  l_number := 8;
  l_varchar := l_number;
end;
```

Comment: You might want l_varchar to be more than 1 character long, though.  ;-)